# Extjs elements destroy/fly

Tags: extjs4

I'm loading dynamic pages into Html id using load() function. So i want to destroy/clear/fly all Elements(including javascript objects) which are loaded previously into the Html id After destroy the previous loaded elements then new content should be load in to Html id. I'm rendering Extjs form panels and popup in each pages.When i'm trying to load same page again popups are not displaying because previous elements not destroying. Whts the wrong with my approch.

```
var content_div = Ext.get(div_id);
content_div.load({
url:BASE_URL+url_href,
scripts:true,
text: 'Loading...',
params:{id:'123'}
});
content_div.show();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var content_div = Ext.get(div_id);
content_div.update("");
content_div.load({
   url:BASE_URL+url_href,
   scripts:true,
   text: 'Loading...',
   params:{id:'123'}
});
content_div.show();
```